# FieldInfo.SetValue vs Type.InvokeMember(fieldName, BindingFlags.SetField)

Tags: .net, reflection

What is the difference b/w using FieldInfo.SetValue vs Type.Type.InvokeMember(fieldName, BindingFlags.SetField, ...) ?

Answer (score 2):

Type.InvokeMember(fieldName, BindingFlags.SetField, ...) internally calls FieldInfo.SetValue, so there are no differences, except additional checks in Type.InvokeMember